# Calculating total amount from nouisliders

Tags: nouislider

I want the amount of two noUiSliders to autoupdate as I slide and be displayed at the Sum.

The value from the first slider to be multiplied with the value from the second slider, then multiply that again by 110. The result will then display in the span sum.

```
    <h2>Antall selgere <span id="selgere"></span></h2>
    <div class="slide_selgere"></div>

    <h2>Antall pakker <span id="pakker"></span></h2>
    <div class="slide_pakker"></div>

    Sum: <span id="sum"></span>
```

My script is as follows:

```js
$(".slide_selgere").noUiSlider({
    start: [ 5 ],
    step: 1,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    range: {
        'min': [ 1 ],
        'max': [ 10 ]
    }
});

$(".slide_selgere").Link('lower').to($('#selgere'));

$(".slide_pakker").noUiSlider({
    start: [ 15 ],
    step: 1,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    range: {
        'min': [ 1 ],
        'max': [ 100 ]
    }

});

$(".slide_pakker").Link('lower').to($('#pakker'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another `.Link()` on *both* sliders:

```js
var sliders = $('.slider'), sum = $('#sum');

sliders.Link().to(function( value ){
    // Use .not() to filter the sliders, finding the one that *didn't* change.
    var total = Number(value) + Number(sliders.not($(this)).val());
    sum.html(total);
});
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/uujcj8g5/).

Comment: Thank you so much for a great slider and great help!